# The minus sign and the case

Tags: spacing

Please consider the following:

```
$$ g(y) = \begin{cases}
y + 1, & \text{for } -1 \leq y \leq 0 \\
1 - y, & \text{for } 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases} $$
```

When it gets rendered, I am getting a fairly long minus sign before the 1 and a space between the minus sign and the 1. I do not like that. Any suggestions?

Comment: please post complete documents that can be run to show the problem, but you can force the prefix spacing with `{-1}` (but note `$$` is not latex syntax)

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note you shouldn't use the plain TeX construct `$$ ... $$`. You can solve the problem with a pair of braces. I added an improvement for the inequalities:

```
  \[ g(y) = \begin{cases}
y + 1, & \text{for } {-1} \leq y \leq 0 \\
1 - y, & \text{for } {\phantom{-}0} \leq y \leq 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases} \]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is because the `-` acts like a *binary* operator within your context (`\text{for }` on the left and `1` on the right). You can either place everything in the conditional clause of `cases` inside `\text` and escape math as necessary, or make the operator *unary* (with braces; actually making it *ordinary*):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  g(y) = \begin{cases}
    y + 1, & \text{for $-1 \leq y \leq 0$} \\
    1 - y, & \text{for $0 \leq y \leq 1$} \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\[
  g(y) = \begin{cases}
    y + 1, & \text{for } {-}1 \leq y \leq 0 \\
    1 - y, & \text{for } 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Using `{-1}` would also work, forcing `-` to be an *ordinary* symbol, similar to `{-}1`.

Comment: Fine and useful explanation for beginners! (+1)